# Как правильно расставить ковычки в JS коде

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

Имеется JS скрипт (показываю фрагмент):

```
<script>
....
out +='{% if '+response.statuses[i]+'=="Художник" %} Картины художника';
out +='{% elif '+response.statuses[i]+'=="Мастер ДПИ" %} Изделия мастера ДПИ';
out +='{% else %} Работы художника и мастера ДПИ';
out +='{% endif %}';
...
document.getElementById('alert3').innerHTML = out;
...
</script>
```

Как правильно расставить ' чтобы этот фрагмент корректно выводился в html? response.statuses[i] - переменная, которая получается при переборе значений JSON словаря по ключу.

Этот фрагмент кода добавляет html код, написанный с использованием встроенного тега if (тег Django). Это и создало трудности при расстановке ковычек.
Буду рада любой помощи.

Comment: А что сейчас не так? Какой результат получаете и какой ожидаете? Точно ли это все силами js делается?

Comment: В таком виде вообще не работает. Ошибка - Could not parse the remainder: '"Художник"' from ''+response.statuses[i]==+'"Художник"'

Comment: Ошибку кто говорит? javaScript? Или, как я подозреваю, библиотека python? Отредактируйте вопрос. Добавьте туда полный текст ошибки и добавьте нужные теги

Comment: Должны меняться подписи кнопок в зависимости от знаачения response.statuses[i] Я бы показала, но не могу сюда скрин вставить

Comment: Это полный текст ошибки. Да, хорошо, добавлю тег python и django, главное чтобы это помогло)

Comment: Полный текст ошибки приложите. Как я понимаю, вы это циклом формируете, тогда нужна структура `response.statuses` ну и сам цикл хотябы в примерном виде.

Comment: выглядит будто идет попытка использовать серверный код django на клиенте из-за смешивания не работает ни на сервере ни на клиенте

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Процесс поиска уточнений привёл меня к верному решению.

Answer (score 1):

Решила свою проблему, переписав код используя JS вместо встроенного тега if Django. Видимо неверно трактовались в js скрипте вставленный html код с {} (фигурными скобками) от тега if (тег Django).

```
if (response.statuses[i]=="Художник") {
out +=' Картины художника';
}
else if (response.statuses[i]=="Мастер ДПИ") {
out +=' Изделия мастера';
}
else {
out +='Работы художника и мастера ДПИ';
}
```